# OpenAM add user via rest api fails (missing required sn)

Tags: openam

The default OpenAM schema requires the sn and cn attributes when using the /identity/create service.  Even though I'm specifying them in the request, I get an error on the back end saying sn is missing... Has anyone else got the create identity endpoint to work?

I'm using OpenDS for the backing ldap and version 9.5.4 for OpenAM.  All the other endpoints (authenticate, logout, isValidToken, update) work just fine.

Request:

```
http://openam:8080/openam/identity/create?admin={token}&identity_type=user&identity_name=jdoe&identity_realm=/&identity_attribute_names=userpassword&identity_attribute_values_userpassword=changeme&identity_attribute_names=givenname&identity_attributes_values_givenname=tbd&identity_attribute_names=sn&identity_attributes_values_sn=tbd&identity_attribute_names=cn&identity_attributes_values_cn=tbd
```

Exception:

```
exception.name=com.sun.identity.idsvcs.GeneralFailure Plug-in com.sun.identity.idm.plugins.ldapv3.LDAPv3Repo encountered an ldap exception. LDAP Error 65: The requested operation will add or change data so that the data no longer complies with the schema.
```

OpenDS Error:

```
ADD RES conn=82 op=20 msgID=33882 result=65 message="Entry uid=jdoe,ou=people,dc=company,dc=com violates the Directory Server schema configuration because it is missing attribute sn which is required by objectclass person" etime=0
```

---

Update:

It look like by the time it gets to the LDAPv3Repo, the sn and cn attributes have been dropped:

```
LDAPv3Repo:07/02/2012 05:52:17:986 PM PDT: Thread[http-bio-8080-exec-2,5,main]
exit addAttrMapping: attrMap = {mail=[], sn=[], cn=[], inetuserstatus=[Active], givenname=[], userpassword=xxx..., dn=[]}
```

There is nothing else in the debug log that looks like it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you are hitting a typo, and unhelpful error messages.

Your userpassword pair

```
identity_attribute_names=userpassword&identity_attribute_values_userpassword=changeme
```

should be

```
identity_attribute_names=userpassword&identity_attributes_values_userpassword=changeme
```

with an extra s at the end of the second attribute. You are likely to find the OpenAM mailing list more responsive for OpenAM questions (https://lists.forgerock.org/mailman/listinfo/openam)

Comment: I found this too this morning debugging the server, though actually the issue is that with the update command, it needs to be "identity_attribute_values_*" (singular rather than plural).  The extra "s" on the cn and sn values is what the issue was.